# I am using camanJS to apply a filter to a photo. Currently running into an issue where the application of the filter crops the photo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, camanjs

[**Link to fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4fssbenf/7/)

Whenever I run the program without the Javascript code, the image loads perfectly fine without the cropping effect. However, when I run the program with the Javascript code, the image crops.

**HTML**

```
<img src="my data:image" id= "hello" height = "208" width = "264">
```

**Caman Code**

```
var vintage = $('#vintagebtn');
Caman("#hello", function () {
 this.vintage();
 this.render();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the dimensions of the picture using the `<img>` tag `width="264"` and `height="208"`, set the width and height using CSS.

**CSS**

```
#hello {
  width: 264px;
  height: 208px;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

[**JSFiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4fssbenf/9/)